# Angular 2 Service returns object object

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

thank you for your time in advance, I'm trying to display a collection I pulled from a local mongodb collection.
http://localhost:8080/player/all is the API endpoint which returns the right data when I test it with postmaster. It's an array of objects. The HTML only shows [object Object] for each object like:

[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Is there any problem with the service or the component?

Backend is an express/node app

**player.component.html**

```
<div> {{allPlayers}} </div>
```

**player.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from '../../services/auth.service';
import {PlayerService} from '../../services/player.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-player',
  templateUrl: './player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./player.component.css']
})
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit {
  allPlayers: Array<Object>;


  constructor(private authService:AuthService,
              private router:Router,
              private playerService: PlayerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.playerService.getAllPlayers().subscribe(allPlayers => {
      this.allPlayers = allPlayers;
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });
  }
}
```

**player.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class PlayerService {


  constructor(private http:Http) {

 }

  getAllPlayers(){
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/player/all")
        .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable holds a list of objects. You are binding the object/array in the UI so it's saying [Object Object] as its string representation

To get all the values you can use *ngFor and get individual value and show.

```
<ul>  
  <li *ngFor="#player of allPlayers">
    {{ player.name }} is {{ player.age }}.
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or as @saneetharan suggested you can bind individual properties of the objects in side array by there index values.

Answer (score 4):

**use angular pipe**

```
{{allPlayers| json}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the properties using **`dot`** operator when you are displaying inside the template, or use ngFor if its an array.

```
 <div *ngFor="let player of allPlayers">
  {{player.firstName}}
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. ngFor also returns [object Object]. I want to display the array with the objects just like the API returns it.

Comment: can you post what is the data you are getting in

Comment: `[{"_id":"58d309f396c356946e700044","firstName":"LeBron","lastName":"James","overall":96,"position":"SF","salary":25,"duration":1,"notes":"Birdrechte","yearsInTeam":10,"team":"TOR","lastTeam":"","birthYear":1984,"age":32}]`

this would be the first object. there are over 500.

Comment: did the answer help?

Comment: Yes thank you. So I have to stringify the object if I want the whole one?